# How to adjust and shape the subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.5, subplot

I am trying to plot 2 plots in one figure. So just 2 subplots and adjust the figure sizes and find a decent one. At the moment I am using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np    

#####  import data #####

df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\Kevin\Documents\Afstudeer\Measurements/1st_plot.txt',sep=',',decimal='.',header=None)
df.columns=['Vx','Vy','undefined','Laser_signal']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5)) 
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)

ax1.plot(df['Vx'],df['Vy'],label='plot')
plt.xlabel(r'$V_x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$V_y$')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)

ax1.scatter(df['Vx'],df['Vy'],label='data_points')
plt.xlabel(r'$V_x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$V_y$')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, bottom=.45, right=.8, top=.95,
                wspace=.3, hspace=.4)
```

so its this last code that is confusing me. When i do the plot, i get something like this:

[image]

Here is my sample data:

```
-1.725953467,0.109343505,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.725953467,0.110607445,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.729140157,0.110607445,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.722766777,0.10839555,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.727865481,0.11534722,-10.433363664,0.159359499
-1.726272136,0.112503355,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.731689509,0.120086995,-10.433363664,0.159359499
-1.727228143,0.117559115,-10.433363664,0.159359499
-1.729140157,0.11977101,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.730096164,0.121350935,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.729458826,0.122614875,-10.433363664,0.159043752
-1.735832206,0.12482677,-10.433363664,0.159359499
-1.728821488,0.121350935,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.733920192,0.124510785,-10.433363664,0.159359499
-1.731052171,0.12166692,-10.433363664,0.159675246
-1.739018896,0.12735465,-10.433363664,0.159043752
-1.738062889,0.12861859,-10.433363664,0.159043752
-1.738700227,0.133358365,-10.433363664,0.159043752
-1.73455753,0.12988253,-10.433363664,0.159043752
-1.743161593,0.144101855,-10.433363664,0.159043752
```

As you will see from the code, I am only taking the 1st 2 columns. I am expecting 2 subplots in a one figure. So why do i get these up and bottom lines between the plots??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lines

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5)) 
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
```

are somehow mutually exclusive. Either you create the subplots via

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 5))
```

or you create them via

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
```

After that better use the axes handles `ax1` and `ax2` to set any properties, e.g.

```
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$V_x$')
```

instead of `plt.xlabel`.

Comment: haha... Thank you very much. Created the subplots makes life easier.